# How to retrieve images that are stored in database table on the jsp page using struts2 tags when its corresponding description is selected?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, struts2, sql-server-2012

I have created a table with Descriptions and its corresponding image paths as ***"C:temp\Box Images\Box diecut.jpg"*** in the database. And, this path refers to the server where the images are stored.

My goal is to display,say, image1 when description1 is selected from the list, likewise display image2 when description2 is selected.

Do I need to use `<s:property value="imagepaths"/>` in the html5 tag of `<img src="<s:property value="imagepaths"/>"/>` to get the imageslist and write a script "onselect" description to produce images.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This property doesn't change until the new action is executed, why do you need this property?

Comment: To get the value from imagelist.Is there another way to retreive the images list and put them is the img src of the html5 tag?

Comment: The `imagelist` might contains multiple items, but it holds only `imagepaths`. Given that path you can retrieve the image from the disk or db, don't know what you asking in the title, and load with `img` tag. But you can't load whole list at once, you need to do it one upon a time.

Answer (score 0):

Github/Vkdon93/closewold
Here I already solved it. The project actally too big maybe u need to dig inside it. 
For your question store the images with their link in the db and call it as < img src=c:/a. Jpg>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I have the link ?